# SVM classification training RFE with caret fails

Tags: r, svm, r-caret, rfe

I'm trying to perform a classification of some raster data with the `caret` package. With `RandomForest` everything works fine, I just want to try the SVM classifier, but I get an error.

Data is aggregated from different rasters (1x1 km, 50cm resolution aggregated to 2.5m with the statistics max, min, mean, median and std), stored in a data frame like this:

[Unscaled table with classification training data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6NSq.png)

Then I scale this data with the following code (training_high_final is the training table, Column 1 is "index" and column 22 is the "classvalue":

```
# scale and center data
thf_scaled <- as.data.frame(scale(training_high_final[,c(-1,-22)], center= T, scale = T))
# Reset Row Numbers
rownames(thf_scaled) <- seq(length=nrow(thf_scaled))
thf_scaled$index <- training_high_final$index
thf_scaled$id <- as.factor(training_high_final$classvalue)
```

Scaled table looks like this:
[Scaled table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLLzf.png)

The code for the Reverse Feature Elimination where the error occurs:

```
# RFE-Control
# for random forest
# ctrl_rfe <- rfeControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 9, repeats= 5, functions = rfFuncs, allowParallel = T)
# for SVM
ctrl_rfe <- rfeControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 9, repeats= 5, allowParallel = T)
sizes = c(1:20)

# RFE (Col 21 is index (not needed), Col 22 the classvalue)
rfe_high <- rfe(thf_scaled[,c(-21,-22)], thf_scaled[,22], sizes = sizes, rfeControl = ctrl_rfe, method="lssvmPoly")
```

Result:

```
> rfe_high <- rfe(thf_scaled[,c(-21,-22)], thf_scaled[,22], sizes = sizes, rfeControl = ctrl_rfe, method="lssvmPoly")
Error in { : task 1 failed - "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"
```

I was trying it before with many more variables (now there are only 20, before I had ~80) and got the error

> task 1 failed - "stopping".

There are 170 training samples without NA data.